# header to mobile site and header to normal page

Tags: php, javascript

I have chosen to be mobile things under the same with the database so it does not manage to get my page / code, do not know if it is a good idea or do you have a andne idea for it? ..

What I would like it to do is it to find out whether it is mobile or whether it's just a browser you are logging on.

```
function db_c()
     {
         $link = @mysqli_connect('localhost', '..', '..', '..');
         if(!$link)
         {
             die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
         }
         mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
         $this->mysqli = $link;
         
         
         function detect_mobile($ua=null) {
             $ua = ($ua) ? $ua : $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];    
             return (preg_match('/(alcatel|amoi|android|avantgo|blackberry|benq|cell|cricket|docomo|elaine|htc|iemobile|iphone|ipad|ipaq|ipod|j2me|java|midp|mini|mmp|mobi|motorola|nec-|nokia|palm|panasonic|philips|phone|playbook|sagem|sharp|sie-|silk|smartphone|sony|symbian|t-mobile|telus|up\.browser|up\.link|vodafone|wap|webos|wireless|xda|xoom|zte)/i', $ua));    
         }
 
 
         if(detect_mobile($ua) ) {
            header('Location: http://mobil.blabla.dk/');
         }
         else{
             header('Location: http://www.blabla.dk/');
         }
 }
```

**Error her:**

Notice: Undefined variable: ua in /home/jesperbo/public_html/blabla.dk/inc/function_php/function.php on line 39 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/jesperbo/public_html/blabla.dk/inc/function_php/function.php:39) in /home/jesperbo/public_html/blabla.dk/inc/function_php/function.php on line 43

line 39 is here:

```
 if(detect_mobile($ua) ) {
```

line 43 is here:

```
header('Location: http://www.blabla.dk/');
```

I try to take this into my hand, but then go on over and nothing will show on the page https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

If I have done like this:

```
function detect_mobile($ua=null) {
             $ua = ($ua) ? $ua : $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];    
             return (preg_match('/(alcatel|amoi|android|avantgo|blackberry|benq|cell|cricket|docomo|elaine|htc|iemobile|iphone|ipad|ipaq|ipod|j2me|java|midp|mini|mmp|mobi|motorola|nec-|nokia|palm|panasonic|philips|phone|playbook|sagem|sharp|sie-|silk|smartphone|sony|symbian|t-mobile|telus|up\.browser|up\.link|vodafone|wap|webos|wireless|xda|xoom|zte)/i', $ua));    
         }
 
 
         if(detect_mobile() ) {
            header('Location: http://mobil.blabla.dk/');
         }
         else{
             header('Location: http://www.blabla.dk/');
         }
```

you will see it show like this:

Denne webside har et loop ved omdirigering
Websiden på blabla.dk/ har forårsaget for mange omdirigeringer. Dette kan muligvis løses ved at rydde dine cookies for dette website eller ved at tillade tredjepartscookies. Hvis dette ikke hjælper, ligger problemet muligvis i din serverkonfigurationen og ikke din computer.
Her er nogle forslag:
Genindlæs denne webside senere.
Få flere oplysninger om dette problem.
Fejl 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): Der var for mange omdirigeringer.

http://billedeupload.dk/images/fOUIQ.png

So if I spend $ua better yet the last I show here:

*Hope you can help me :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:

```
if(detect_mobile($ua) ) {
```

To:

```
if(detect_mobile() ) {
```

The `detect_mobile` method will supply the user agent for you if you don't supply it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To detect if its mobile or regular, you should check http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ You can download a detector in most coding.

Keep in mind that this is never 100% certain. A user on a mobile computer could browse just like a regular browsers. Also a user might want to see the regular site, even when on a mobile browsing is mobile.

Detecting is good, but try to give the user a choice.

Header already send means there was output to the browser. You can use output buffering like `ob_start();` to catch all output so this problem doesnt happen. But better is to make sure there is no output. This also means there is no SPACE or new line outside the `<?php ?>` tags on any of the included files.

Comment: What are you thinking when you say that burgers should only be chosen if he will be on the mobile side or the normal page?

Comment: When im using my mobile to browse websites I often get a mobile page similar to what you are doing. Often these pages contain less information or options. So I would like a choice to use the regular site on my mobile.

Comment: Oohhh...it is dejligt på learn something new all the time :) and the works fint now :)

It is clearly something I will weather! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, redirection need to be done before any actual output.

In your case, there's some content already sent to client and that's why you cannot redirect the user.

So instead of doing it like:

```
<? 
db_c();
detect_mobile();
// other stuff
?>
```

Do it that way:

```
<?
    detect_mobile();
    db_c();
    //other stuff
?>
```

And to check if user is using desktop browser or his mobile phone/tablet etc use this class: [php-mobile-detection](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/)

And then you can use it like this:

```
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    // redirect here
}
```